# Gradle Plugin Task Reflection Scans Plugin's Project Class Files Instead of Current Project Files

Tags: java, gradle, reflection, annotations, guava

I've created a Gradle plugin which scans the class files in my project and find which ones have an annotation.

I got it to work and compiled it. Now when I run the task in my project, instead of scanning the classes of the project that I'm in and runs the task on it, it scans the class files of the plugin project itself. What am I doing wrong?

```
final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        ClassPath classpath = ClassPath.from(loader); // scans the class path used by classloader
        log.info("classPath = {}", classpath);
        for (ClassPath.ClassInfo classInfo : classpath.getTopLevelClassesRecursive(packageName)) {
            log.info("classInfo={}", classInfo);
            Class<?> clazz = classInfo.load();
            if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class)) {
                Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
                for (Method method : methods) {
                    doSomething(clazz, method);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        String errorMsg = new StringBuilder("Unable to generate ").append(propertiesFileName).append(" file.").toString();
        log.error(errorMsg, ex);
        throw ex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a lot of digging in Gradle forums, and still, I'm experiencing many issues with that, but this is the best solution I could found:

```
URL[] urls;
List<URL> listOfURL = new ArrayList<>();
SourceSetContainer ssc = getProject().getConvention().getPlugin(JavaPluginConvention.class).getSourceSets();
File classesDir = ssc.getByName("main").getOutput().getClassesDir();
listOfURL.add(classesDir.toURI().toURL());
urls = listOfURL.toArray(new URL[0]);
final ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work the way you expect:

1. Your project class files are, by default, not loaded by Gradle as part of building your project. They will be produced by compilation, loaded by test execution, etc ... but normally not as part of Gradle executing tasks.
2. When your plugin reaches out to classloaders, it is in the managed Gradle world, which has its own tricks with classloaders. So you would have to understand which tricks are pulled ... but given 1, that would still not work.

Given that what you are attempting looks a lot like [annotation processing](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder), you should investigate that way of handling your needs.